# How to best describe this code using TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, vue.js, frontend

Here is an object with several different key and value, and each props of value differ from each other, how to best describe this object using TypeScript? Especially the `setValue` method, how to limit type of the `creatureType`, `prop` and `value`?

```
 const object = {
      john: {
        name: '',
        age: 18
      },
      alien: {
        height: 20,
        power:100,
      },
      setValue(creatureType) {
        const self = this
        return function (prop) {
          return function (value) {
            self[creatureType][prop] = value
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: The method is something like `(prop: string) => (value: any) => void` but honestly I would use real setters instead. Wrap them in a lambda if you want to expose them without passing out a reference, but don't have a method return a closure. You've entwined policy with implementation here.

Comment: Sorry, my English is not very well, do you mean the closure is not a good practice? Could you give an example? Thanks a lot

Comment: `class Foo { bar: string }; const foo = new Foo(); export const setter = (prop: string) => (val: any) => foo[prop] = val;` The instance is local to the module, and that way you don't clutter the class implementation with access policy. You'll probably want to use generics rather than `any` though, see jcalz's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `setValue()` method will need to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) if you want it to place strong restrictions on which properties and values go with which, uh, "creature type".  Because the type of the `object`'s `setValue()` method will be dependent on the type of the other properties of `object`, the compiler will give up trying to infer types for it; it's too circular for something that isn't a `class`.  Either you could manually annotate all the types, which would be annoying, or you could split `object` into two pieces, say `plainObject` holding just the data, and then merge in the `setValue()` method which will be dependent on the type of `plainObject`, like this:

```
const plainObject = {
    john: { name: '', age: 18 },
    alien: { height: 20, power: 100 }
}
type PlainObject = typeof plainObject;

const object = {
    ...plainObject,
    setValue<K extends keyof PlainObject>(creatureType: K) {
        const self: PlainObject = this;
        return function <P extends keyof PlainObject[K]>(prop: P) {
            return function (value: PlainObject[K][P]) {
                self[creatureType][prop] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And you can verify that the compiler behaves as you want:

```
object.setValue("john")("age")(19); // okay
object.setValue("alien")("height")("pretty tall"); // error!
// "pretty tall" isn't numeric --> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
object.setValue("john")("power")(9000); // error!
// "power" is wrong --> ~~~~~~~
object.setValue("elaine")("name")("elaine"); // error!
// "elaine"? -> ~~~~~~~~
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code in Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgGwIYEswHkBGArApsWAXhgG8BYAKBmpmxAAswAuUmMJAW1xYHIeAaGEgDm3GAEYAHDAC+-SjSEIUuZq3q4Uw+lBYAmAAyC4IAO64ATi3EGDsyjMpQAnnFwwACsjRY8BGMQubiAAZvDeGDj4UADclJSgkLAgUf7E5FQ0AHQ5iKiRflDymdQQuFAAakgIAK64ADwA0jC4AB5QqgAmEDAA1rjOoZ4RvtEAfAAUwBa4SFA1MwAqrmKNAJSkCoo0idAwZQghLF75o2kwUPQoEHEl2zPzFmAwITVgBCjgMPUeLe1dPX6gzCJx8qSgAG1GgBdSZwCwgODHDYZbZomAPBbPV7vKCfZ4TABu1TqxxG4Kh0IhHmhKK26PRBxCEOms0euGWbip8MR0ICMGJtVwtwZikcdzF9PsFHFMEoKUKWTKlRJuAmACI6Ix1WsNSJcDqJuIAJxrGIwAD0FpgIF6SGc8vBSvKVSFeuUqkN6o0Wh0Xvh5RcF2qCB15qtLQsCIsAEJKBH1QGoEGoCH1TBrmAeLAwDUuBYUMAYABaYtjGAAPyr1Zr1cdiuVrrqGq1YH9ZkshuNtgMZst1ss0bjFATJnMFnT1xgpgRYGEJbLldrFfr0WdKrd6twEQNuvV7C4Xu3+V34YHUZAsfj1q3O-VAH4S+Xl1X4hRKEA)